# Complex mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I'm new at mongo and I'm trying to do a simple query (at least in sql it simple) but I can't get it right. I use java driver.
My collection contains documents:

```
{"name":"bb",
 "action": {"Type":"Buy","amount":78},
 "date": "Jan 31, 2013 10:31:20 AM"}
```

I want to find if a user: "bb" did Buy actions in last month with amount over 1000 in total ( I want to `$sum` the amount)
How do I do it in Mongodb?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: 'bb'}},
    {$unwind: '$action'}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$name', sum_amount: {$sum: '$action.amount'}}},
    {$match: {sum_amount: {$gt: 1000}}}
])
```

Would do the trick. I assume here the only type of action is `buy`, if that is not the case you can do an extra `$match` after the `$unwind`:

```
{$match: {'action.Type': 'Buy'}}
```

To get only `Buy` types.

Comment: Thanks, How do I add a condition for operation made only for the last mounth?

Comment: If you store the date as a date format - not a string then you can do a range query ($gte and $lte) for the match, limiting the results for the aggregation.

Comment: @user1109846 As Ross said, if you store your dates in ISODate() format (BSON Dates) then you can just do a simple $gte than another date of one month ago